# How to continue execution after a throw exception in Java?

Tags: java, domexception

I am reading HTML files from a folder using xml parser that store the clean code in tagNode

```
try {
    Document doc = new DomSerializer(props, true).createDOM(tagNode);
} catch (Exception ex) {
 ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

But one of the files is giving me an error :

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified.
```

How I can continue running the program after the exception is caught ?

---

solution #1

```
    try 
    {
            File folder = new File(path);
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("dataset.txt");
            BufferedWriter br= new BufferedWriter(fstream);


for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {    
{
        try {
            Document doc = new DomSerializer(props, true).createDOM(tagNode);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

---

Given a way around it , why I am getting this error ?

Comment: The whole point of `try-catch` is so that you can continue your program if an exception occurs, can you post the exception handling that you are doing?

Comment: Does it make sense continuing running the program without a valid `doc`? If so, just catch the exception and react appropriately. Or do you mean `continue parsing after this exception`?

Comment: [RTFM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)

Comment: I was using 1 try/catch for all program . Now I used outer try/catch and try/catch for DOMException . So for some reason I got this error and the program continues.

Comment: There is no need for nested try catch blocks - you can have multiple catch blocks to deal with different exceptions in different ways, but the whole point is to have a single try block. Once you've caught the exception, execution continues on the next line after the last catch block (whether an exception was thrown or not).

Comment: `for {...}`?? What kind of for loop is that? Please post real code.

Comment: Please check the update solution#1 for more code . I don't know if this can be done with 1 catch/try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are processing a list of files like you mention above you only need the `try-catch` block that is inside of the for loop:

```
File folder = new File(path);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("dataset.txt");
BufferedWriter br= new BufferedWriter(fstream);

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)  
{
    try 
    {
       Document doc = new DomSerializer(props, true).createDOM(tagNode);
    } 
      catch (DOMException de) 
      {
         de.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a try/catch block

```
try{
   Document doc = new DomSerializer(props, true).createDOM(tagNode);
}
catch(DOMException e){
   //error handling here if you want
}

 //we now hit more code
```

Comment: What do you think of mu solution #1 ?